# Mysql - Count and group by return zeros

Tags: mysql, join, count, subquery

I know, this question was askes some more times but I just cant get it.

**The important columns:**

- name
- date
- category

**Saved Data:**
Every name is stored multiple times even with the same category like:

```
name | category | date
-----|----------|-------
jeff | exCat    | 2015-07-02
paul | red      | 2015-07-04
jeff | red      | 2015-07-03
paul | blue     | ...
kevin| green    | ...
jeff | green    | ...
mike | red
```

In this case **>>** *Exclude jeff and output all others.*

**The Goal:**
Select all names in between two dates not having a specific category (called "exCat" here) anywhere in this timespan.

Sounds easy doesnt it? Well, cant get it anyway. The first part is easy:
`SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE date >= @start AND date <= @end` (Could use `BETWEEN` too).

Then I would need something like `WHERE category NOT LIKE "exCat"`.
This wont work. This query would output me everyone who got at least one other category beside "exCat". But I need the guys not even one time containing "exCat" in this specific timespan.

**One possible thing:**

```
SELECT 
    name AS Name 
FROM myTable 
WHERE date >= @start AND 
      date <= @end AND 
      Name NOT IN (SELECT 
                       name 
                   FROM myTable 
                   WHERE date >= @start AND 
                         date <= @end AND 
                         category LIKE "exCat")
GROUP BY name
```

So this would be just like `SELECT name WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name WHO GOT AT LEAST 1 "exCat")`
Like this I would exclude only people who got at least one "exCat" e.g. I would get a result with people not having "exCat" anywhere.

**The problem with that:** Every subquery needs about 0.05 seconds, both together like this about 15 minutes. Thats too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT name
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN category = 'exCat' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

This is a way of excluding only people who got *at least one* `exCat` without using a sub-query.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/922f1f/1)

Comment: I get a syntax error. Isnt that possible with `CASE WHEN category LIKE "%something%" THEN 1 END` ? If not maybe I could use a equivalent with OR's (multiple category != "something")

Comment: @C4ud3x Are you using double quotes instead of single?

Comment: Just tried out with single ones. Still gives me a syntax error.

Comment: For sure my mistake, sorry. Perfect solution, just what I was hoping to get. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT name
 FROM mytable
 GROUP BY name
 HAVING NOT FIND_IN_SET('exCat', GROUP_CONCAT(category))
```

Comment: An explanation would improve the answer and increase the chance of it getting upvoted.